# Microsoft Teams sending bad requests to aiohttp botframework server when deployed to google cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, botframework, microsoft-teams

I was developing a bot for microsoft teams with the botframework. Everything worked fine locally when using public IP addresses provided by negrok (e.g. forwarding `https://7669460caeba.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3978`). I always changed the "Messaging endpoint" in the bot profile (https://dev.botframework.com) to point to `https://7669460caeba.ngrok.io/api/messages`

Then, after making SSL certificate for my https domain (the domain is redirected to the public IP address of the google cloud instance), allowing the 3978 port in firewall settings in Google Cloud, I deployed the bot to Google Cloud. Also, I changed the "Messaging endpoint" in the bot profile to `https://myhttpsdomain.com:3978/api/messages`.

However, I started to get 400 error code (Bad Request) when receiving request from Microsoft Teams servers. Apparently, the aiohttp server cannot decode the incoming requests from Microsoft Teams throwing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 276, in data_received
    messages, upgraded, tail = self._request_parser.feed_data(data)
  File "aiohttp/_http_parser.pyx", line 523, in aiohttp._http_parser.HttpParser.feed_data
aiohttp.http_exceptions.BadStatusLine: invalid HTTP method
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Why are you trying to use port 3978 for your public Google endpoint. Your localhost needs this so it doesn't conflict with other things that might be running on your local workstation on 80 or 443, but for your actual production hosting, on https, it's basically using 443. Try take it out and use https://myhttpsdomain.com/api/messages . Of course, if this works, remember to remove port 3978 on your google cloud settings

Comment: 3978 is the port my botbuilder server application is listening on. If I did not specify the port in the bot framework profile, I would have to redirect https://myhttpsdomain.com/api/messages to https://localhost:3978/api/messages.

Comment: Anyways, do you think that the problem might be that https domain needs (for some authentication purposes) to be specified as https://myhttpsdomain.com/api/messages, and only then redirected to the 3978 port on the instance (http://localhost:3978/api/messages)?

Comment: you definitely need to tell ngrok to forward to 3978, but that's purely a requirement of local workstation development. For live hosting (testing/production/staging), like hosting your bot on Google, you definitely don't need any other ports than normal (well, basically 443/httpS).

Comment: I don't think it's an authentication issue, I think it's a physical running issue - your app is probably NOT actually running on 3978 inside the Google cloud instance, it's probably ONLY running on 443

Comment: The error is `invalid HTTP method`. This means that your code is not expecting/cannot handle the HTTP request. Methods are HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, etc. Edit your question and show the incoming HTTP request and the code that is handling the request.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the one creating the request - I don't know what request causes the error. I have problems receiving a request from Microsoft Teams created on some activity (message send, button clicked, user added...). I have tried sniffing the incoming traffic with tcpdump but did not get any useful info apart from the 400 code.

Comment: @kmartin - Have you tried changing your messaging endpoint from `https://myhttpsdomain.com:3978/api/messages` to `https://myhttpsdomain.com/api/messages` like Hilton suggested? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: You might not be the one creating the request but you can see the request on the receiving side. The receiver (listener) is the side reporting the error.

Comment: @JohnHanley well spotted, I didn't see that right at the end of the trace. kmartin, Teams will basically be sending you a POST message, you need to make sure there's nothing stopping that from being received and processed. It should be fine if you're handling it locally, but perhaps there's some configuration missing (not much python experience I'm afraid).

Comment: Thank you all, in the end, removing the port from the endpoint address (as suggested by @KyleDelaney) worked. Anyways, it troubles me, why it wasn't working before when I tried it multiple times :D Thanks, @Hilton, for the comment about 443 port. Although my app ran on 3978, the 443 was apparently needed for establishing communication.

Answer (score 0):

Port numbers should only be used with `localhost`. When you've published your bot to a remote server with a domain name and everything, you should omit the port number so that it can use the default port.

Answer (score 0):

The 'HTTPNotFound' error suggests that the incoming request does not match any of the routes defined in you application. This can happen when the endpoints specified by Microsoft Teams doesnot match the 'api/messages' route.

It works for me I have changes message endpoint on Azure service bot (my bot) bot i have created like,

**Error**
url:

> https://good-mackerel-hugely.ngrok-free.app

**Solved**

> https://good-mackerel-hugely.ngrok-free.app/api/messages

Change in bot message endpoint